# Adding a new item to ebay using ebay API or any other format using PHP

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-design-templates

Hi everyone i have a professinal  account with a limit but i cant understand how do i upload new listing in antiques, painitngs furniture  jewelery and silver categories.

Is there anone who  is able to help and guide me and my Head of it(he works on PHP) to set up listings automation on ebay. We have a store and we are interested in Automatisation of putting newly added items to our website on ebay we sell unique items, each item is only one no stock, or different models.

And once item is sold, to be able to take it off ebay or set it as sold automaticly.

I know that there ias an API but it is very compleacted. if any one of you can help me with my taks  i would be thankfull and if needed we may discuss a monetary compensation.

Tried to do uploads via a csv file but it didnt work a single time. AS WE HAVR MULTIPLE CATEGORIES  we are lost in what we should do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have unique items it is easier to work with OLD `AddItem` of trading API: you can find details [Here](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html)

If you set quantity to 1, once the item is sold, quantity it is automatically set to zero (or item is delisted) therefore do not need to do anything.

Stackoverflow is a place where you can find hints, suggestions and help to solve your problems, but it is not the place where can find ready-to-use solutions.